# How to add missing files while publishing addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, outlook, outlook-addin

I made an OUTLOOK addin using C# on Visual Studio 2015.
The addin works perfectly on my system but when i use the addin on other system it stays inactive even after enabling the addin,
So i tried installing it with the dependent  text file on their local disk C.
It worked.

How to add all the files including the DLL and the txt file present in my local disk to the addin while publishing it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I came up with a solution, instead of adding those text file separately.
I wrote a code where those files were being created if the dependent text files are not found.

Attaching the code to create new file through C#

```
 if (!File.Exists(mgrFile))
 {
   StreamWriter sw = null;

   using(var stream = File.Open(mgrFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read)) {
     using(sw = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
       sw.Write("ak@test.com");
     }
   }
 } else {
   mgrMail = File.ReadAllText(mgrFile);
 }
```